# Delimit decimal number from string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

Hi I have string and the data are not proper,

I need to delimit the string at the end of the number

The string is `In moreH$450pacific much liquormk H2.55pacific Z,H430, 430`

the number may have comma(,) in between the number.

I need to split into

```
in more H - $450
pacific much liquormk H-2.55
pacific Z- H430, 430"
```

I new to python, so please guide me to put a regex for my use

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Asking for a regex without even trying does not really fit here... please see [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `re.findall` here:

```
inp = "In moreH$450pacific much liquormk H2.55pacific Z,H430, 430"
parts = re.findall(r'.*?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!,?\s*\d)', inp)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['In moreH$450', 'pacific much liquormk H2.55', 'pacific Z,H430, 430']
```

The strategy of the regex is to match all content up until the first numeric content which does not fail the negative lookahead.  Here is the logic:

```
.*?            match all content up and including the nearest
\d+(?:\.\d+)?  number, possibly with a decimal component
(?!,?\s*\d)    which is NOT followed by either a comma, whitespace, and another number OR
               just another number
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex in `re.findall`:

```
>>> s = "In moreH$450pacific much liquormk H2.55pacific Z,H430, 430"
>>> print ( re.findall(r'.*?\d+(?:\s*[,\.]\s*\d+)*', s) )
['In moreH$450', 'pacific much liquormk H2.55', 'pacific Z,H430, 430']
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `.*?\d+`: Match 0 or more characters followed by 1+ digits
- `(?:\s*[,\.]\s*\d+)*`: Followed by dor or comma with surrounding whitespaces and followed by 1+ digits